# how to fix this error with OutlinedTextField and DropdownMenu?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I have the code below. I want to create an OutlinedTextField it fill in using the drop-down menu

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val suggestions = listOf("Item1","Item2","Item3")
var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

var textfieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero)}

val icon = if (expanded)
    Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp //it requires androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended
else
    Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown


Box() {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = selectedText,
        onValueChange = { selectedText = it },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                //This value is used to assign to the DropDown the same width
                textfieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
            },
        label = {Text("Label")},
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(icon,"contentDescription",
                Modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded })
        }
    )
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(with(LocalDensity.current){textfieldSize.width.toDp()})
    ) {
        suggestions.forEach { label ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                selectedText = label
            }) {
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

[image: But I have this problem]
[image: Text Error]

I couldn't find the solution

*can you help me??*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
suggestions.forEach { label ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                selectedText = label
            } , text = {   Text(text = label)})
        }
```

Comment: Yes it works thank you.
I want to make the OutlinedTextField not writeable, but only a selection from the dropdown list.
Can you help me?

Comment: no I don't find it